# Element wise mean for a list of dataframes with NA

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames x and I want to find the mean of each element across the data frames.  I found an elegant solution online courtesy of Dimitris Rizopoulos.

```
x.mean = Reduce("+", x) / length(x)
```

However this doesn't really work when the data frames contain NA.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: `matrices` or `data.frames`?  there is a difference

Comment: Sorry I meant data.frames.  Edited to remove matrix in the last line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `data.table`

The steps are  (1) coerce each data.frame [element] in `x` to data.table, with a column (called `rn`) identifying the rownames. (2) on the large data.table, by rowname calculate the mean of each column (with `na.rm = TRUE` dealing with `NA` values). (3) remove the `rn` column

```
library(data.table)


results <- rbindlist(lapply(x,data.table, keep.rownames = TRUE))[,
                     lapply(.SD, mean,na.rm = TRUE),by=rn][,rn := NULL]
```

an alternative would be to coerce to matrix, "simplify" to a 3-dimensional array then apply a mean over the appropriate margins

```
    # for example

    results <- as.data.frame(apply(simplify2array(lapply(x, as.matrix)),1:2,mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Works perfectly.  Really appreciate the step by step explanation of the code as well.

Answer (score 5):

I like @mnel's solution better, but as an educational exercise here's how you can modify your expression to work with `NA` values while keeping the same type of logic:

```
Reduce(function(y,z) {y[is.na(y)] <- 0; z[is.na(z)] <- 0; y + z}, x) /
  Reduce('+', lapply(x, function(y) !is.na(y)))
```

Comment: `replace` works on a `data.frame`, so you could do something like `nax <- function(x, replace.with = 0) replace(x, is.na(x),replace.with); Reduce(lapply(x, nax), f = '+') / length(x)`

Comment: @mnel: this probably won't be the mean intended. You're dividing by the length of x, but if there are NAs in some of the data frames for the given cell, then you probably want the mean of the non-NAs, which is * / length(!is.na(<current cell>)).